# Expected Value and coding

Tags: probability

last week I had a test in which I didn't completely understand a question the teacher made:
he asked to calculate the Entropy of a 3-extended source of two values (0 and 1) that have 1/3 and 2/3 probability respectively. After that I had to calculate a Huffman code for the 8 source codes of the extended source and the average length of such resulting code.

So far so good, until he suggested that S, emits n = 300'000 binits and such sequence is coded with the Huffman code I already defined. So, if X is the random variable that measure the length of the resulting coded sequence, how much is E[X]?

I tried to apply the usual formula for calculating the expected value as usual so I divided n (300'000) by all the possible lengths I got from my Huffman code. Then I multiplied each of these values by the corrisponding probabilities (in example 300000/2 * 8/27 ecc..)...but...it gives me a number (112037,00...) that doesn't help me.

My question is: I did it correctly?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code we get?

\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{|l|c|l|}
 \hline
 & \text{Weight} & \text{Code} \\
 \hline
``000" & 1 & 0100 \\
``001" & 2 & 000  \\
``010" & 2 & 0101 \\
``011" & 4 & 011  \\
``100" & 2 & 001  \\
``101" & 4 & 111  \\
``110" & 4 & 110  \\
``111" & 8 & 10   \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{align*}

When there are 3 binits, the expected length of encoded message is

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}(X) &= \frac{76}{27}
\end{align*}

By linearity of expectation, when there are $300000$ binits, it is

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E}(X) &= \frac{76}{27}\cdot 100000 \approx 281481.48 \text{ bits}
\end{align*}

Comment: oh thank you very much for your help! Finally I have a clue on this!

Comment: You are welcome!